# Can nginx stream work with multiple SSL certificates?

Tags: nginx, ssl, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to set up nginx as a front-end to IIS 7 so that I can set up multiple SSL certificates with single IP, something IIS does not support (shocker).

The way I see it, I neither need or should be interfering with the HTTP layer at all, or any of the unencrypted data for that matter (because of Exchange's NTLM Authentication that is bound to the TCP session instead of individual requests). I should set up nginx to handle only the SSL layer.

Luckily, it supports doing that! But not with multiple certificates, apparently?

Basically this is what I'm trying:

```
stream {
    upstream http_backend {
        server 192.168.1.1:80;
    }

    upstream https_backend {
        server 192.168.1.1:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_pass http_backend;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate      certs/default.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  certs/default.key;

        ssl_certificate      certs/domain1.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  certs/domain1.key;

        ssl_certificate      certs/domain2.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  certs/domain2.key;

        proxy_pass https_backend;
        proxy_ssl on;
    }
}
```

According to [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html), `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` can be called multiple times, but for the purpose of specifying certificates of different types, not for different domains. In this case, the last pair simply overrides the previous ones, and becomes the only certificate you negotiate with when trying to access the server, regardless of the host name used.

In `stream` mode I cannot set up multiple `server` entries in the same port just changing `server_name` like I can in `http` mode, in fact `server` does not support `server_name` at all when used in the `stream` context, so it's unclear how I'm supposed to solve this.

I've been Googling all day and can't figure out a solution. Perhaps nginx just doesn't support what I need? And in which case, is there an alternative?

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please edit your question to add more detail. Here are some questions which might help add appropriate information. Why do you need to use stream rather than server? Are all the services on the same domain or different domains / subdomains? I'd have expected you just have a server for each service, with whatever cert is required inside the server.

Comment: @Tim 1. Because stream doesn't modify the HTTP context which is what I want; 2. Yes I have many domains; 3. Evidently I have no intention of renting and managing a Windows server for each domain just so I can have Exchange e-mail, that's absurd, and I don't want to pay extra for multiple IP addresses either.

Comment: @Tim Mind I already achieved what I want, just not the way I wanted it. My nginx proxy is scrapping a bunch of HTTP headers and functionality to workaround the fact that some IIS features do not follow the standard HTTP protocol to work, which causes conflicts with nginx.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarity / completeness if you want some help.

Comment: @Tim It is covered in the question.

Comment: You're generally more likely to get help if you give additional information when it's requested.

Comment: I'm not surprised IIS 7 doesn't handle certificates the way you want. It is more than 10 years old, after all. Consider using a modern web server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's the problem, I can't, not without having to change the operational system as well because IIS is tied to the OS and Exchange relies heavily on it. At any rate, most other HTTP servers support this feature since forever, and Windows 2008 is still maintained so I guess Microsoft just likes being 10 steps behind on everything-server.

Comment: Microsoft almost never releases significant new features in old OSes.

Answer (score 1):

So I had an epiphany and managed to crack this problem.

Turns out you don't need to set up SSL mode or any certificate in the stream `server` entry to get `ssl_preread` to work, and this possibilitates an interesting workaround.

I can set up multiple `server` entries on arbitrary ports listed for `localhost` only, each one with a different certificate, and have a main `server` on port 443 routing the incoming connections to the correct one.

Here's a basic configuration with 3 certificates:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
}

stream {

    // IIS server
    upstream https_backend {
        server 10.0.0.1:443;
    }

    // set up SSL session with the default certificate
    upstream default {
        server 127.0.0.1:4430;
    }
    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:4430 ssl;

        ssl_certificate certs/default.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key certs/default.key;

        proxy_ssl on;
        proxy_pass https_backend;
    }

    // set up SSL session with certificate for marvel.com, www.marvel.com
    upstream marvel {
        server 127.0.0.1:4431;
    }
    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:4431 ssl;

        ssl_certificate certs/marvel.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key certs/marvel.key;

        proxy_ssl on;
        proxy_pass https_backend;
    }

    // set up SSL session with certificate for dccomics.com, www.dccomics.com
    upstream dccomics {
        server 127.0.0.1:4432;
    }
    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:4432 ssl;

        ssl_certificate certs/dccomics.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key certs/dccomics.key;

        proxy_ssl on;
        proxy_pass https_backend;
    }

    // route connection to the tunnel with correct certificate
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
        marvel.com marvel;
        www.marvel.com marvel;

        dccomics.com dccomics;
        www.dccomics.com dccomics;

        default default;
    }
    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
}
```

So as far as SSL and NTLM Authentication goes this is working wonders, the only thing I'm lacking with this set up is the possibility to register the real user IP on IIS logs, since I can't set `X-Forwarded-For` in HTTP headers.